# Given a list of lists, how to get a group of lists like output_1 with python without pandas?

Tags: python

this code groups a N-by-2 array,

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6]})
df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list)
```

by the values in first column

```
[['A' '1']
 ['A' '2']
 ['B' '5']
 ['B' '5']
 ['B' '4']
 ['C' '6']]
```

and get this result (output_1)

```
a
A       [1, 2]
B    [5, 5, 4]
C          [6]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

I am trying to do this job without pandas

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
list(groupby(ds,key = itemgetter(0)))
```

it seems that I grouped the data array successfully,

```
[('A', <itertools._grouper at 0x121f779e8>),
 ('B', <itertools._grouper at 0x121f77588>),
 ('C', <itertools._grouper at 0x121f77400>)]
```

right now, I am stuck on getting these elements.

```
list(list(groupby(ds,key = itemgetter(0)))[0][1])
```

gave me a empty list `[]`

how to get a group of lists like output_1 with python without pandas?

Comment: What is the expected result? Is it like `[('A', [1, 2]), ('B', [5, 5, 4]),('C',[6])]`?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use defaultdict from collections.

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6]}
results = defaultdict(list)
for index, value in zip(my_dict['a'], my_dict['b']:
    results[index].append(value)
```

Now we have grouped value for a given index, we can get back to the desired output like this

```
final = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in results.items():
    final["a"].append(key)
    final["b"].append(value)
```

final result should looking like this :

```
{"a" : ["A", "B", "C"], "b" : [[1, 2], [5, 5, 4], [6]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your first attempt, `groupby` yields the key and an iterator to each elements that fits the key as each of its items.

You can extract the data using a list comprehension :

```
[(key, [elem[1] for elem in it]) for key, it in groupby(ds,key = itemgetter(0))]
```

or, as dict:

```
{key: [elem[1] for elem in it] for key, it in groupby(ds, key=itemgetter(0))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

ds = [
    ['A', '1'],
    ['A', '2'],
    ['B', '5'],
    ['B', '5'],
    ['B', '4'],
    ['C', '6']]

groups = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in ds:
    groups[key].append(value)

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['5', '5', '4'], 'C': ['6']})
```

You can convert the defaultdict to a list, if you want with

```py
list(groups.items())
```